# Delete All .log files execept for one

Tags: command-line, delete, extension

I want to delete all files with `.log` extension on except for one. Is it possible to  do that delete all `.log` files from all folders except for mongodb log files?

Comment: How are the MongoDB logs named? Also, how are the other ogs named?

Comment: show us sample log files names for both unwanted and wanted logs!

Comment: I want to delete all .log files except "mongodb.log"

Comment: no matter what names other files have. if extension is .log delete it except "mongodb.log"

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `find` command, but be careful while using it - you might end up removing everything you have.

- **Important:** First you have to run the command without the `-delete` option to make sure the output is what you want to delete. Notice that `-name` looks for exact filename.

  ```
  $ find -not -name mongodb.log -name "*.log"
  ```
- If the output is proper and you're sure the command locates only the files we want to remove, then you have to add the `-delete` option to the END of the command.

  ```
  $ find -not -name mongodb.log -name "*.log" -delete
  ```

  The order of the options for `find` is significant, and in this case if `-delete` option is placed anywhere other than the end of the command - it will remove everything.

#### Example

Imagine we have these files:

```
$ ls
1.log  2.log  3.log  4.log  5.log  bar  foo  mongodb.log
```

Let's list all `*.log` excluding `mongodb.log`. Check the output and make sure it doesn't contain anything except `log` files.

```
$ find -not -iname mongodb.log -name "*.log"
```

- Notice the `-iname`! to keep both upper and lowercase versions of `mongodb.log`.

Then remove them using:

```
$ find -not -iname mongodb.log -name "*.log" -delete
```

Check again and you will see the log files are gone as expected but `mongodb.log` remains there.

```
$ ls
bar  foo  mongodb.log
```

Answer (score 5):

To delete all files except the one named `mongodb.log`, you can use extended globbing. First, enable the option:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

And then, you can run:

```
rm !(mongodb.log)
```

Or, to delete only files with a `.log` extension, but not `mongodb.log`, you can do:

```
rm !(mongodb).log
```

For example:

```
$ ls
file1  file2  file3.log  file4.log  file5.log  mongodb.log
$ rm !(mongodb).log
$ ls
file1  file2  mongodb.log
```

if you need this to be recursive, to match files in subdirectories as well, you can use the `globstar` option:

```
shopt -s globstar
```

And then run:

```
rm **/!(mongodb).log
```

For example:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── baz
│       └── bad
│           ├── file1
│           ├── file2
│           ├── file3.log
│           ├── file4.log
│           ├── file5.log
│           └── mongodb.log
├── file1
├── file2
├── file3.log
├── file4.log
├── file5.log
└── mongodb.log

$ rm **/!(mongodb).log

$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── baz
│       └── bad
│           ├── file1
│           ├── file2
│           └── mongodb.log
├── file1
├── file2
└── mongodb.log

3 directories, 6 files
```

---

From `man bash`:

> If the **extglob** shell option is enabled using the shopt builtin,
>   several extended pattern matching operators are recognized.  In  the 
>   following    description, a pattern-list is a list of one or more
>   patterns separated by a **|**.  Composite patterns may be formed using one
>   or more of the fol‐    lowing sub-patterns:
>
> ```
>       ?(pattern-list)
>              Matches zero or one occurrence of the given patterns
>       *(pattern-list)
>              Matches zero or more occurrences of the given patterns
>       +(pattern-list)
>              Matches one or more occurrences of the given patterns
>       @(pattern-list)
>              Matches one of the given patterns
>       !(pattern-list)
>              Matches anything except one of the given patterns
> ```

> **globstar**
>
> If  set,  the  pattern ** used in a pathname expansion context will match all files and zero or more directories
>   and subdirectories.  If the pattern is followed by a /, only directories and subdirectories match.